# How to display only one form in Zend Framework 1?

Tags: zend-framework

In Zend Framework 1, I wrote code for one form but it displays two forms. How to fix it?

```
<form name="sample"> .... </form>
```

Comment: Refresh page and check it on different browsers .also check  any other form tag already have or not

Comment: We'll need to see your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I had checked all of these(any other form tag already have or not) and (Refresh page and check it on different browsers)

Comment: I tried it with the same backup code. It works fine
Thank you.